# Is this regular function globally rational?

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry

Let $\mathbb{k}$ be an algebraically closed field of characteristic not 2 or 3, and let $X \subseteq \mathbb{A}^2_\mathbb{k}$ be the locally closed subset given by

> $X = \{ (x,y) : x^3=y^2, (x,y) \neq (1,-1) \}$.

Consider the function

> $f \colon X \to \mathbb{k}$ with $f(x,y) = \frac{1-y}{1-x}$ for $x \neq 1$, and $f(1,1) = \frac{3}{2}$.

$f$ is easily seen to be a regular function of $X$ (aka a morphism $X \to \mathbb{A}^1_\mathbb{k}$ of varieties), since it can be written as $f(x,y) = \frac{1+x+x^2}{1+y}$ for $y \neq -1$. However, I guess that $f$ cannot be represented by a single rational function on $X$.

Can anyone give me a hint how to prove this (if I am not mistaken)? I would also be happy to see more simple examples of this phenomenon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose for simplicity that ${\rm char}(k)=0.$ Suppose for contradiction that we have $f(x,y)=P(x,y)/Q(x,y)$ where $Q(x,y)$ does not vanish on
$X.$ Thus we have
$$
f(t^2,t^3)=(1-t^3)/(1-t^2)=(1+t+t^2)/(1+t)=P(t^2,t^3)/Q(t^2,t^3)
$$
for all $t\not=-1,1$ and $P(1,1)/Q(1,1)=3/2$. In particular $Q(t^2,t^3)\not=0$ for all $t\not=-1$.
Hence we must have $Q(t^2,t^3)=c(1+t)^n$ for some $c\not=0$ and some $n\geqslant 0$.
However, since the $t$-coefficient of $Q(t^2,t^3)$ vanishes by construction and the $t$-coefficient of
$c(1+t)^n$ does not vanish for any $n\geqslant 1$, we see that $n=0$.
So $Q(t^2,t^3)=c$. Now since the above equalities are true for infinitely many $t$, we have the polynomial
identity
$$
(1+t)P(t^2,t^3)=c(1+t+t^2)
$$
but this is impossible because $1+t$ does not divide $1+t+t^2$.

Answer (score 0):

I was previously confused about what it means to write a regular function as a single expression, but I think I have a clearer picture now. I still think the issue is that the closed subscheme $p = (1,-1) \in \text{Spec}\,\mathbb{k}[x,y]/(y^2 - x^3)$ is not "cut out by one equation." However, I think the correct way to translate the (vague) quoted phrase into a rigorous statement is to say that the associated divisor $m \cdot [p]$ on the curve is not principal for any positive integer $m$ -- it is not the divisor of zeros of some regular function on the curve.

Let's start by considering an example where the closed subscheme we cut out is actually a principal divisor. Consider excising the closed subscheme $y = -1$ from the cuspidal cubic curve. Then the divisor corresponding to $y = -1$ is principal: it is given by formally summing the three zeros of the function $y+1$ on the curve (one can write this divisor as $[\omega] + [\omega^2] + [1]$, where $\omega$ is a primitive third root of unity). Once we've removed all three of these points, the function $\frac{1+x+x^2}{1+y}$ is defined everywhere on the curve. And moreover, it is fairly easy to see that any rational function on this open subscheme can be written in terms of a single expression, because the ring of regular functions is $(\mathbb{k}[x,y]/(y^2 - x^3))_{y+1}$.

However, I claim that the divisor $m \cdot [p] = m \cdot [(1,-1)]$ is not principal for any positive integer $m$. Indeed, if it were, then there would be a polynomial $f(x,y) \in \mathbb{k}[x,y]/(y^2 - x^3)$ whose vanishing locus would intersect the cuspidal cubic curve at $p$ with multiplicity $m$, and there is no such $f$.

Comment: Unfortunately it is not true that the OP's set $X$ is affine. The proof you wrote is correct, but it proves something completely different, and it cannot be adapted for the OP's set.

Comment: @Nefertiti Thanks for the comments, I have revised my solution. I was misinterpreting what it meant for a rational function to be expressible as a single function...

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Currently, I am not able to follow your whole argument due to my limited expertise on divisors (I am working on that). Still, I have the feeling that your argument just shows that there have to be regular functions on $X$ which are not globally rational. It does not show that my concrete map $f$ can not be expressed by a rational function, right?

Comment: @Dune We have to be much more precise when saying ``regular function on $X$'' and ``globally rational.'' I am fairly confident that my argument shows what you want, that your concrete map $f$ cannot be expressed as a globally-defined quotient of polynomials. This is only possible if the point $p$ is cut out set-theoretically by one equation.

Comment: For $U \subseteq X$ open, a function $f \colon U \to \mathbb{k}$ is rational, if it can be expressed as $f(x) = g(x) / h(x)$ for all $x \in U$, where $g,h$ are polynomials (note that $X \subseteq \mathbb{A}^2$ by assumption, so polynomials are well defined). A function is regular, if it is locally rational, i.e. for each $x \in U$ there is an open neighborhood $O$ of $x$ such that $f_{|O}$ is rational. I hope now it is completely clear, what I mean - I don't know yet, how to translate this into scheme-theoretic language...

Comment: @Dune Great. Let me also remark that your question is one of the major motivations for scheme-theoretic considerations, because they avoid the problems of the nature you describe. It isn't exactly necessary to write down formulas for the regular functions on a curve; all we need to know is that they form a ring, called the ring of global sections of the structure sheaf.

Comment: Maybe this is a scheme-theoretic reformulation of my question: For an affine scheme $\mathrm{Spec}(R)$, the ring of sections on a principal open subset $D(f)$ is defined as a localization $R_f$. Let's assume we would define the ring of sections on an arbitrary open set $U$ as localization $S^{-1}R$ ($S$ consisting of all global sections which do not vanish on any point of $U$). Why wouldn't we get a sheaf in that way?

Comment: @Dune It is *not* in general true that arbitrary open subsets $U \subset \text{Spec} \, R$ can be expressed as $\text{Spec}\, S^{-1}R$ for some multiplicative set $S$. This is definitionally true for principal open sets, but consider the open subscheme obtained in $\mathbb{A}_{\mathbb{k}}^2$ by cutting out the origin -- this is not expressible as $\text{Spec} \, S^{-1}\mathbb{k}[x,y]$ because, for instance, it is not affine, as I proved in my earlier irrelevant answer to your question!

Comment: I know, but this is a different phenomenon. Note that although $Y = \mathbb{A}^2 \setminus \{0\} \subseteq X = \mathbb{A}^2$ is not affine, its ring of sections $\mathcal{O}_X(Y)$ in $X = \mathrm{Spec}(\mathbb{k}[T_1,T_2])$ is a localization of $\mathbb{k}[T_1,T_2]$ (it is even equal to $\mathbb{k}[T_1,T_2]$).